# How to define android:label for different productFlavors in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

Is there a way to specify different app label (name) for different productFlavors in build.gradle? For example something like this:

```
productFlavors {
    stage {
        app name with "-stage" suffix
    }
    preprod {
        app name with "-preprod" suffix
    }
    prod {
        app name without any  suffix
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine suggested a very nice solution based on [injecting build variables into the manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables). It even allows to use localized app labels. So here it is:

1) Specify `android:label` in `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

`android:label="${appLabel}"`

2) Specify a default value in app level `build.gradle`:

`manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel:"@string/appName"]`

3) Override the value for needed product flavours:

```
productFlavors {
    stage {
        manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel:"@string/appNameStage"]
    }
    preprod {
        manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel:"@string/appNamePreprod"]
    }
    prod {
        // Just let it use a default value
    }
}
```

4) Add string resources which you are referring to (`appName`, `appNameStage`, `appNamePreprod`). Localize them if needed.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve it as follows:

1. Ensure you have specified `android:label="@string/app_name"` in your AndroidManifest.xml.
2. Then remove `app_name` from `strings.xml`

**Change your build.gradle as follows:**

```
productFlavors {
    stage {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "stage"
    }

    preprod {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "preprod"
    }
    prod {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "prod"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Define a string resource in your `main` source set to use for your `android:label` value.

Step #2: In the manifest in your `main` source set, apply that string resource to the `android:label` attribute (e.g., `android:label="@string/whatever"`).

Step #3: For any build type, product flavor, or build variant where you want a different value for `android:label`, create a source set (e.g., `app/src/stage/` alongside the existing `app/src/main/`) and put your desired value in the string resource for that source set (e.g., `app/src/stage/res/values/strings.xml` with a `whatever` string resource).

When you build your app, Android will use the build-specific source set for your string resource, falling back to `main` for situations where you did not override it.

If you definitely want to define it in Gradle — for example, you are generating the label value programmatically at build time — [use `resValue` statements](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code) instead of defining the string resources in XML. You would still use that string resource in the manifest, and I would recommend still having a default value in `app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

You can create with `resValue "string", "app_name", "label (name) "`. Remove `app_name` from your `string.xml` file.

like :

```
productFlavors {
    stage {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Stage"
    }
    preprod {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Preprod"
    }
    prod {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Prod"
    }
}
```